# Electron Geolocation Network location provider

Tags: node.js, express, electron

So I've got this code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(console.log, console.error, {timeout:5000});
```

And its returning the following error:

```
GeolocationPositionError {code: 2, message: "Network location provider at 
'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received."}
code: 2 message: "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received."
```

I dont seem to find any solution for this. I've already tried to set `process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY = config.GoogleAPIKeys.GeolocationAPI;` (the config part is right I double checked it)

And I also switched to ssl (https) and added this in order for electron to diplay it  `app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-certificate-errors', 'true');`

Thanks in advance!